# set the Z-order of an iframe object

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, menu, z-order

I am using Javascript for a menu bar with drop-down submenus.  But these drop-down menus appear under my iframe object and are not visible.  How do I set the Z-order of the menu to be greater than the iframe?

You can see an example here http://theiatech.com/papers.php?paper=5.  The applications menu for example has 4 submenu items but only 3 are visible.

Comment: It doesn't do it on Chrome 10.

Comment: but it works on FF 4.0.1 by default.  Try this: http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showpost.php?s=ae2f4833d7b85614293c2c45d5fbdae8&p=2358869&postcount=4

Answer (score 0):

most important for z-index is to have the parent container set to a kind of position (relative or absolute). (for sure you need to put them into the same container if you want to z-order them against each other).

and the containing objects should have a position as well...

so far my experinces with z-index usage.